# Endpoint request returns other endpoint response in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

I have a file called "forms.routes.js" listing a mix of `router.get`, `router.post`, `router.put`, `router.delete` endpoints.

For some reason when I request this endpoint (16th on the list):

`localhost:3000/v2/forms/:domain/config/active` [GET] - router.get('/:domain/config/active', auth.jwt, controller.getActiveUnfinalizedConfigs);

it goes to the first endpoint on the list and returns the response from the controller method associated with the first router.get:
`router.get( '/:domain/:entity/:type', auth.jwt, validate([param('entity').trim().isString().withMessage('must be alphanumeric')]), controller.getForms );`

But when I move that endpoint (16th on the list) to the first router declaration, it hits the correct controller. Can't figure out why the order is affecting the endpoint requests mainly the GET requests.

I moved the incorrect GET endpoint router to be the first router GET call and it does request to its corresponding controller method as expected. But would like to know why the order if affecting other endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need better segmentation of your endpoints. When you establish and endpoint at `router.get( '/:domain/:entity/:type'`, everything that comes in of the form `/a/b/c` will match it, no matter what a, b and c are.

Thus if you later declare `router.get('/:domain/config/active'` it will never be reached (for simplicity's sake let's assume that's the case, you could `next()` it). This is because it will first match your initial endpoint and config will populate the entity parameter while active will populate the type parameter.

Add a key word in the route to properly segment out what you're looking for.

i.e. your routes could be
`/:domain/config/:state`
and
`/:domain/info/:entity/:type`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! However, I stuck with a different approach by just reordering the endpoints in this case, the endpoint with the static string parameter to always go on top of the one with multiple :parameter strings so that those are called first. So that's also a reasonable approach?